# Date conversion issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working Code

```
if getdate()>convert(DATE,'09/29/2006')
select 1
else 
select 2
```

Not Working Code

```
DECLARE @1 varchar='09',
    @2 varchar='29',
    @3 varchar='2006'
if getdate()>convert(DATE,@1+'/'+@2+'/'+@3)
select 1
else 
select 2
```

getting issue

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Please suggest me the changes?

Comment: Which version of SQL server?

Answer (score 4):

Always use lengths when using `varchar()`.  Your values are being truncated to one character:

```
DECLARE @1 varchar(255)= '09',
    @2 varchar(255) = '29',
    @3 varchar(255) = '2006'
```

So your date conversion is `'0/2/2'`.

Comment: Commenting to stress the importance of that first sentence.  -Always-

Comment: @NickVaccaro . . . Alas, the great irony is that MySQL and Oracle often do not *allow* the length argument in a place where SQL Server requires it.  The databases can be quite inconsistent on this point.  But with SQL Server, *alway* use the length argument for character types.

Comment: even with pretty much the same answer, and 30s or so quicker, I still get less votes :( - high reputation always gets extra points on here ha!

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the size of the `varchar(n)`, since you will get `varchar(1)` with nothing declared.  Take a look at [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

```
DECLARE @1 VARCHAR(2)='09',
    @2 VARCHAR(2)='29',
    @3 VARCHAR(4)='2006'


if getdate()>convert(DATE,@1+'/'+@2+'/'+@3)
select 1
else 
select 2
```

If you were using 2012+, you could use [CONCAT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh231515.aspx) to combine the string.

```
CONCAT(@1,'/',@2,'/',@3)
```